# How to speed up cassandra node joining the cluster. It takes too much time.

Tags: cassandra

I have 4 nodes-cluster. Cassandra version is 2.1.14.1346. I have also 1.5 TB data. I am trying to adding 4 nodes more. When I check the network sent bytes chart in Opscenter, I see sending data is  20MB/s. I want to speed up joining phase.

I set stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec: 800. But it doesnt work.

At this circumstances, joining 4 nodes takes 48 days. It is not acceptable. Is there any solution?

Comment: are you adding these 4 new nodes as another datacenter, or are you adding them to the current datacenter? if they are a new datacenter, then you need to use `auto_bootstrap: false` and run `nodetool rebuild -- {other_dc_name}` once all new nodes are online: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html

Comment: I am trying to add existing datacenter. I know the differences. I built a lot datacenter. It is my first time to add multiple nodes to existing datacenter which has 1.5TB data. The main issue is slowness of sstable transfer. I have to speed up the transfer and use all the resource of the servers in someway. The datacenter has no load right now.

Comment: did you run `nodetool repair`? it sounds like the new nodes might only be getting new data, and not all the data they should be

Comment: Since new nodes cannot be joined cluster because of data volume i didnt run nodetool repair. I was stuck in joining cluster phase.

Comment: Instead of setting the properties in cassandra.yaml you could use the nodetool setstreamthroughput command as described in https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205409646-How-to-performance-tune-data-streaming-activities-like-repair-and-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the new nodes as seed nodes, then they would join the cluster immediately rather than boostrapping. Once they have joined the cluster, run nodetool rebuild on them to populate them with data.